# Roblox doesn't recognise user has gamepass

Tags: roblox

```
                    local Player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.parent)
                local CoinsI = Player.leaderstats.FolderOfValues.Coins
                local AssetID = 243010855
                
                if MarketPlaceService:PlayerOwnsAsset(Player,AssetID) then
                    CoinsI.Value = CoinsI.Value + CoinClone.CoinsValue.Value * 2
                end
```

> The code is meant to check if the player has the x2 coins gamepass and if the player does, it rewards them with double the coins. I have the gamepass and it gives me no coins. Can anyone help?

Comment: this is in a module script, under a server script in serverscript service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID you have supplied is a gamepass id, not an asset id.

To check if a player owns the gamepass, you should use a different method instead, which is [UserOwnsGamePassAsync](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/MarketplaceService#UserOwnsGamePassAsync)

If considering your current naming convention, it'd be something like:

```lua
...
local GamepassID = 243010855
...
if MarketPlaceService:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(Player.UserId, GamepassID) then
...
```